# Force on charge inside cavity

Tags: electrostatics

Suppose we have a conductor with a cavity of arbitrary shape inside it.Now we introduce a point charge + q inside the cavity in an arbitrary position.Will the charge experience any force due to the charge induced by it on the cavity,or not?If not,then how can it be shown mathematically?also if yes,how to do that?
At first glance it appears that as the charge induced on the walls is entirely due to the point charge the overall field on it should be zero,but this being a very vague thought,it has to be treated mathematically.How to do this?

Comment: No math, just my "feeling": Assume a spherical cavity and place the point charge in it's center. Due to symmetry, there is no net force acting on the charge. Now move the charge somewhat off-center. Now the field at the conductor's surface is stronger at the point where the charge is closer -> greater charge induced -> net force in this direction.

Comment: Also the solid angle subtended in the direction where more charge is induced will be lower;so they may cancel out

Comment: This problem can be easily solved using the method of images. The resultant force is nonzero unless the charge is at the center of the cavity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the charge experience any force due to the charge induced by it
>   on the cavity,or not?

(1) the force on the point charge (if any) must be from a non-zero electric field (within the cavity) due to the induced charge on the inner surface

(2) if there is no force on the point charge, there is zero electric field due to the induced charge

(3) if there is zero electric field due to the induced charge, the electric potential (within the cavity) due to the induced charge is *constant*

(4) if the electric potential due to the induced charge is constant, the potential at the inner surface, due to the induced charge, is constant

(5) the (total) potential at the inner surface, due to *both* the induced charge and the point charge, is constant (conductor is an equipotential)

(6) the potential at the inner surface due to the point charge is not, in general, constant

(7) thus, the potential at the inner surface due to the induced charge is not, in general, constant

(8) thus, the potential within the cavity due to the induced charge is not, in general, constant

(9) thus, the electric field within the cavity due to the induced charge is no, in general, zero

(10) thus, the force on the point charge in the cavity is not, in general, zero